# How to set return value in variable and use in other place in a particular action(just like instance variable in ruby)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

```
app.get('/sitemap',function(request,response){
    var query =  JSON.stringify(request.query.transaction_id).replace(/(^"|"$)/g, '').replace(/\s+/, "") ;

    var transaction_details = MongoClient.connect(uri,function(err,db){
        db.collection('TransactionStatus',function(err,collection){
            if(err) {
                throw err;
            } else {
                collection.findOne({_id:query},function(err, doc){
                    return doc;
                });
            }
        })
    })

    console.log(transaction_details);

    response.render(path.join(__dirname+'/sitemap.ejs'),
        {details:transaction_details}
    );
});
```

I am getting ****undefined**** when rendering the file with the variable transaction_details. I am not able to set return value in transaction_details.I am newbie in Nodejs, so any help or advice would be appreciated.

Thanks for your help in advance :)

Comment: You can't `return` from async calls...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't `return` from an async call like that... you need to utilize callbacks:

```
app.get('/sitemap',function(request,response){
    var query =  JSON.stringify(request.query.transaction_id).replace(/(^"|"$)/g, '').replace(/\s+/, "") ;

    var transaction_details = function(callback) {
        MongoClient.connect(uri,function(err,db) {
            db.collection('TransactionStatus',function(err,collection){
                if(err) {
                    throw err;
                } else {
                    collection.findOne({_id:query},function(err, doc){
                        callback(doc);
                    });
                }
            })
        })
    }

    transaction_details(function(data) {
        response.render(path.join(__dirname+'/sitemap.ejs'),
            {details:data}
        );
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks for the quick reply. As per your said I modified the code, but after all the changes. When trying to again load the file getting the below error ** Error: Failed to lookup view "/home/apol/nodejs-testapp/sitemap.ejs" in views directory "/home/apol/nodejs-testapp/views" **

Comment: Do you have a view called that in that directory...?

Comment: I kept the sitemap.ejs file in the views directory. It should get the file. But I don't know the reason why the file is not getting.

Comment: I solved the render problem, i tried to render in diffrent way. So it worked fine. Thanks for letting me know the callback thing.That was really great help for me. I will be looking forward to get more advise from you in future.Thanks :)